# ServiceStack - Unit of work and structure map

Tags: c#, web-services, structuremap, servicestack, unit-of-work

I am making a rest service using ServiceStack (http://www.servicestack.net). I'm using the unit of work pattern for my data access layer. I am using StructureMap to connect all my services and the unit of work together.

What I need to do is to create a single unit of work for each individual request that I receive and then dispose of it after.

I have a WCF Service which is using the mechanism here, http://andreasohlund.net/2009/04/27/unitofwork-in-wcf-using-structuremap.

Essentially resulting in something like this

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.Scan(a =>
        {
             a.AssemblyContainingType<IUnitOfWork>();
             a.WithDefaultConventions();
        });

    x.For<IUnitOfWork>().LifeCycleIs(new WcfOperationLifecycle());
}
```

I am looking for a similar 'Lifecycle' for ServiceStack.

**[Solution]**

The solution is in the comments of the accepted answer.

a) Set the StructureMap lifecycle to HttpContext

```
x.For<IUnitOfWork>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.HttpContext));
```

b) Updated the structure map IOC adapter to extend the IRelease interface

```
class StructureMapContainerAdapter : IContainerAdapter, IRelease
{
    public T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>();
    }

    public T TryResolve<T>()
    {
        return ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance<T>();
    }

    public void Release(object instance)
    {
    ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just want [Request Scope](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container)?

Also check out the concrete [Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Service.cs) base class on how you can use Lazy loading + `Dispose()` to get this behaviour.

As well as in [ServiceStack's new API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) you can override your services `OnBeforeExecute()` `OnAfterExecute()` event hooks by using your own **ServiceRunner** (in the older API you would need to provide a custom service base class).

Comment: To use request scope I'd have to switch to using the inbuit 'Funq' rather then using structure map though right?

Comment: The built-in RequestScope is on Funq, otherwise just use the Request Scope on your preferred IOC with `ContainerAdapter`. Look at the bottom of the wiki for how you can release resources back into your IOC, e.g. getting your ContainerAdapter to also implement `IRelease`

Comment: I had some trouble getting the 'ServiceRunner' to work. I eventually figured out that it doesn't work if your service extends the 'RestServiceBase' class, it only works when extending 'Service' class. This doesn't seem to be mentioned in the documentation anywhere.

Comment: Umm, ServiceRunner is introduced as part of the new API docs? and my answer specifically mentions: `in the older API you would need to provide a custom service base class`